# Google Play Certificate on AIR applcation

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

Hi I want to publish my application on Google Play. Google play shows me my public key with some characters.

I know that Air application need .p12 file to create apk file. But how can i create p12 file from this public key.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the self signed certificate, not from the public key. 
read up on the process here!

[Publishing process | Android](http://helpx.adobe.com/digital-publishing-suite/kb/publishing-process-android-amazon-mobile.html)